# Turn knife cut into a lasso knife cut?

Tags: knife-tool

is there a way to to turn knife cut into a lasso knife cut?
So far its just point clicks but ive seen ppl do a lasso version before, just without explaining how they do it

Comment: Do you have an example video or image? so someone can help you

Comment: [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/4nmuig/how_to_do_this_lasso_knife_cut/) indicates that the lasso-like knife cut was removed from blender some time before 2.75

Comment: i think this is it https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/4nmuig/how_to_do_this_lasso_knife_cut/

Yeah seems to be the same thing marty linked to, i guess they removed it then? why would they do that -_-